# How to get UILabel to center text vertically?

Tags: xcode, uilabel, interface-builder, vertical-alignment

I am assigning some text into a UILabel to display a single character, a symbol, with a Unicode value.  Nothing unusual. But it is not being centered vertically when displayed.  I've fiddled with settings, and then read several Stack Overflow questions and answers, but cannot get it to look right.

Here it is when the font is, I think, 14.0. I'm talking about the double-arrow symbol.

[image]

But when I increase the font to make the symbol more visible, notice the arrow is increasingly rendered downwards vertically, closer to the bottom than the top:

[image]

I am assigning the text like this:

```
lblMyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u21D4"];
```

The settings look like this:

[image]

The frames of the 3 labels you see are assigned according to the containing frame. It is very simple. The height of the problematic UILabel is the same as its containing view and same as the labels to its left and right. Each of the 3 labels is 1/3 of the width of the containing view. Notice the text in the labels on the left and right of the double-arrow symbol are centered fine vertically.

How to center the symbol vertically?  Is there something special about a unicode symbol?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details about how the label is created and positioned. Show relevant code and/or constraints. Should be simple to apply constraints to the 3 labels so they all have the same center or baseline adjustment.

Comment: There are no constraints. In this particular case the frames of the 3 labels you see are assigned according to the enclosing frame.  It is very simple. The height of the problematic UILabel is the same as its containing view and same as the labels to its left and right. Each of the 3 labels is 1/3 of the containing view. I edited the question some, clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I did not have Automatically Adjusts Font selected and then proper Autoshrink setting that should accompany it.  In my case I used Minimum Font Size for the Autoshrink setting.